# .pem private key to X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a .pem as private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
KEY
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When I try to convert to X509Certificate2 I get the following error:

> Cannot find the requested object.

What I've tried:

```
static byte[] PEM(string type, byte[] data)
{
    string pem = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    string header = String.Format("-----BEGIN {0}-----", type);
    string footer = String.Format("-----END {0}-----", type);
    int start = pem.IndexOf(header) + header.Length;
    int end = pem.IndexOf(footer, start);
    string base64 = pem.Substring(start, (end - start));
    return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
}

static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificateFile(string filename)
{
    X509Certificate2 x509 = null;
    using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        if (data[0] != 0x30)
        {
            data = PEM("RSA PRIVATE KEY", data);
        }
        if (data != null)
            x509 = new X509Certificate2(data); //Here i get the error
    }
    return x509;
}

client_pk = LoadCertificateFile(@"..\private.pem");
```

Comment: Your file is private key only. It is not a certificate, this is why your code fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can import a **full** certificate from a .PFX file. I think you could convert your .PEM to .PFX with OpenSSL. Here is the code which is worked for me for a .PFX file load:

```
SecureString secStr = new SecureString();
"<your_password>".ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(c => secStr.AppendChar(c));
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import("<your path to .PFX file>", secStr, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```